# Asymptote - modulo not working

Tags: xetex, loops, asymptote

I'm trying to use a modulo in my for loop in asymptote, however it does not compile. I have a syntax error on the modulo line. Without the modulo, it works just fine.

```
   for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
                if (i%2==0){
                    do stuff
                }else{
                    do stuff
                  }
              }
```

Could you please tell me how to write in correctly in Asymptote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the \ before the percent sign

```
if (i\%2==0){
```

Comment: That should not be necessary. I'm wondering what the setup is where this makes a difference.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as TexShop is interpreting % as beginning a comment rather than being the modulo operator within Asymptote. For me, \% did not solve the issue.

Comment: @Ari Gass Can you share your code because it is difficult to interpret the cause of the error.

Comment: My code is in the comment below. Sorry if the preamble is really messy. I tend to cut/paste so I don't accidentally leave something out that I might need.